# Name for a directed acyclic graph with only one path

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a name for a simple graph with a start node, end node, and strict progression from one to the next?  So [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) of start and end are 1, and degree of any other node is 2?

[image]

"Unidirectional path graph"?  Or is there a name for this property, like "mono-path-aticity"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is known as a "path graph" or "linear graph."

Comment: So the property would be "linearity"?

Comment: I had found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory) but that didn't seem right.  Now with your search terms I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph which does seem right.

Comment: Actually, "path graph" does not connote any directionality? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PathGraph.html